# I want to send some data to loaclstorage with useContext properly, how should I do it? (react JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am making my project with Fullcalendar and I have a problem with making it.

first, This is my state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    externalEvents: [],
  });
```

and this is my todo-input form to make a new externalEvent.

```
export default function Todo({state,setState}) {

  
 
  
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [custom, setCustom] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const getColor = (e) => {
    setColor(e.target.value);
  };

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title === "" || color === "") {
      alert("please type what to do or choose a color");
    } else {
      setState({
        externalEvents: [
          ...state.externalEvents,
          { title: title, color: color, custom: custom, id: uuidv4(), },
        ],
      });
      
      localStorage.setItem("todoStore", JSON.stringify(state.externalEvents));
    
      setTitle("");
      setCustom("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
       <form className="todoinput" onSubmit={addTodo}>
            <input
              className="addevent"
              type="text"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Add event"
            />
            <input
              className="detail"
              type="text"
              value={custom}
              onChange={(e) => setCustom(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="detail"
            />
            <select className="selectcolor" onChange={getColor} value={color}>
              <option value="select">select color</option>
              <option value="#34568B">dolphin</option>
              <option value="orange">tangerine</option>
              <option value="#88B04B">grass</option>
              <option value="#6B5B95">violet</option>
            </select>
            <button className="addtodo" type="submit"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle}/> Add todo  </button>
          </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

If I make a new todo it is saved in State and I'm gonna show the list of externalEvents via map() like below

```
<div  id="external-events"   >
              {state.externalEvents.map((event) => (
                <div
                  
                  draggable={true}
                  className="fc-event"
                  title={event.title}
                  data-id={event.id}
                  data-color={event.color}
                  data-custom={event.custom}
                  key={event.id}
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: event.color,
                    borderColor: event.color,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                  }}
                  
                >
                 <div className="fc-event-main">
                <div>
                
                  <strong>{event.title}</strong>
                </div>
                {event.custom}
              </div>
                  
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

The first problem happened here. that mapping part works fine, However, saving it to localStorage part is a little bit tricky
:

```
localStorage.setItem("todoStore", JSON.stringify(state.externalEvents));
```

above code doesn't save the first externalEvent I made and It starts to save it to localStorage from the second one.

The second problem is more tricky. I wanted to show externalEvents even after I rerender(refresh) the page. so I made a DataProvider Component like below

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext} from 'react'

export const DataContext = createContext();

export const DataProvider = (props) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState({
      externalEvents: [],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      const todoStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoStore'))
      if(todoStore) setTodos(todoStore)

    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('todoStore', JSON.stringify(todos));
    },[todos])


  return (
   <DataContext.Provider value={[todos,setTodos]}>
     {props.children}
   </DataContext.Provider>

  )
}
```

above code is a component that I made before to manage the same problem in my other todoproject, So I tried to my current todoComponent with this data provider

like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {DataProvider} from './components/calendar/DataProvider'
...

function App() {
  <>
<DataProvider>
...
<Switch>
...
<Route path="/calendar" component={Calendar} /> // calendarcomponets has above code and components in it
</Switch>
</DataProvider>
  </>
   }
```

So, I thought now, I can change my State
from this

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    externalEvents: [],
  });
```

to this

```
const[state,setState] = useContext(DataContext);
```

However, It seems like It doesn't work because my state already has kind of form
So I changed DataContext like below

```
export const DataContext = createContext({
externalEvents: [],
```

});

But, as you expected It doesn't work at all.
I'm pretty new to use useContext and tbh also new to coding. So I don't know how can I pass my states to DataProvider properly, Can you help me with it?

Thx for reading, your help will be appreciated.